# Append line of text to file using sed with slash

Tags: linux, sed, terminal

I'm trying to append a line of text to a settings files but I keep getting error **`sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command`**

Here is what I'm doing:

**`sed -i 'HAVE_OPENBLAS = \usr' ./settings.mk`**

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you confusing the `-i` (`--in-place`) *command line option* with the `i` *insert command* by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just a simple echo?

```
$ echo 'HAVE_OPENBLAS = \usr' >> ./settings.mk
```

Comment: The behaviour of `echo` when its arguments contain backslashes is unspecified by POSIX. In some `echo` implementations, that `echo '\u'` would be short for `echo '\u0000'` and output a NUL character. [Use `printf` instead](/q/65803).

Comment: How about `echo "\\u"?`  For a simple use-case as this, I reckon weak-quoting is straightforward enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely must do it with `sed`:

- to add the line at the beginning of file:

  ```
  sed -i -e '1i\' -e 'HAVE_OPENBLAS = \\usr' ./settings.mk
  ```
- to add the line at the end of file:

  ```
  sed -i -e '$a\' -e 'HAVE_OPENBLAS = \\usr' ./settings.mk
  ```
- to add the line as line 5, and shift down subsequent lines:

  ```
  sed -i -e '5i\' -e 'HAVE_OPENBLAS = \\usr' ./settings.mk
  ```
- to replace line 5 in the file with the new line:

  ```
  sed -i -e '5c\' -e 'HAVE_OPENBLAS = \\usr' ./settings.mk
  ```

Comment: I need to add it to the end of the file but whenever I do **`sed -i -e '$a\' -e 'HAVE_OPENBLAS = \\usr' ./settings.mk`** I get nothing writtern to my settings file

Comment: Then your `sed` doesn't support option `-i`.  Either you aren't using GNU `sed`, or you're using a really old version of it.